# Inheritance doesn't work in Query

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring and i have an issue with the following query:

```
    String rejected_offer_query = "SELECT b.job_instance_id, b.start_time, count (*) " + 
        "FROM SygaOfferRejected s , BatchJobExecution b, BatchJobInstance bi "+
        "where s.heure_debut = b.start_time " +
        "and s.heure_fin = b.end_time " +   
        "and b.job_execution_id = bi.job_instance_id " + 
        "and bi.job_name = :batchName "+ 
        "and b.status = :batchStatus " +
        "group by b.job_instance_id";
```

It doesn't return data, but it should return one row as a result: (Test made directly with MySql).

I think it's an inheritance problem because when i try to execute the same query with a super class it works :

```
 SELECT b.job_instance_id, b.start_time, count (*) " + 
        "FROM SygaOffer s , BatchJobExecution b, BatchJobInstance bi "+
        "where s.heure_debut = b.start_time " +
        "and s.heure_fin = b.end_time " +   
        "and b.job_execution_id = bi.job_instance_id " + 
        "and bi.job_name = :batchName "+ 
        "and b.status = :batchStatus " +
        "group by b.job_instance_id"
```

The **SygaOfferRejected** class extends the **SygaOffer**, here's the source code;

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@Table(name = "bob_syga_off")
public class SygaOffer {
  @Id
  private long id_offre; 
  private String acteur;  
  private String heure_debut;
  private String heure_fin;

private String reference_offre;
private int retry;
}

------------------------------------------

@Entity
@Table(name ="bob_syga_offr_rejected")
public class SygaOfferRejected extends SygaOffer{

 }
```

Comment: When i removed the inheritance relation and just use the SygaOfferRejected class with its own attributes the query gives the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inheritance strategy is the issue i should specify the TABLE_PER_CLASS type in the parent class :

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

Hope that helps ;)